# tcpdump default capture size differs on similar servers

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, tcpdump

Running `/usr/sbin/tcpdump -n dst ${some_ip} and dst port 80` on two different but similar (distro, version) servers gives me different capture sizes (65535 bytes for one, 262144 bytes for another).

What might cause this difference in tcpdump capture size? What discrepencies might it cause in resulting data output?

EDIT: `ldd $(which tcpdump)` has the same output on both servers:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0xdeadbeef)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xdeadbeef)
    libpcap.so.0.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8 (0xdeadbeef)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xdeadbeef)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xdeadbeef)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0xdeadbeef)
```

Ah, but kernel versions differ, must be something to do with that...

```
capture size 65535:
    Ubuntu 14.04.4, Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
capture size 262144:
    Ubuntu 14.04.5, Linux 3.13.0-116-generic
```

Comment: Are the two network interfaces of the two servers exactly the same ? Same layer 2 ? Same card ? Same driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Snapshot Length**

Look at [tcpdump.org](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.txt) and search for snapshot-length.  The default is based on your version of libpcap or any custom capture driver you are using.

Comment: `libpcap` same versions on both servers, though there are two so's on both, 1.5.3 and 0.8. What other capture drivers might there be?

Comment: Verify that tcpdump in the path is the same on both boxes, `which tcpdump`, then use `ldd tcpdump` to verify what libraries it is using.

Comment: `ldd $(which tcpdump)` has exactly the same filename output on both servers.

Comment: AFAIK, that is hard coded in libpcap, so if they are the same version on both servers, the default snapshot length should be identical.   If this is an RPM based distro, then you could verify the integrity of the files in libpcap and tcpdump to verify someone didn't recompile and overwrite them.

Comment: Ah, I unintentionally lied about the servers being the same, the distro and kernel versions slightly differ (see edit). If no one provides extra info I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: that is intriguing.  I am curious if these are virtual interfaces or if there is something vastly different about the network cards/drivers.  It shouldn't make a difference, but i've seen stranger things.

Comment: These are production servers whose hardware and drivers I don't fully control, but `ethtool`, `lshw` and `lspci` all show the exact same info for the interfaces, so I'm guessing it must be something with the kernel or other distro libs. I could check the changelogs I suppose.